# Kafka - Difference between DefaultPartitioner with MessageKey vs Custom Partitioner?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to send the message to `KafkaProducer` using `ProducerRecord`.

```
new ProducerRecord(topicName,messageKey,message)
```

This uses `DefaultPartitioner`, DefaultPartitioner will use the hash of the key to ensure that all messages for the same key go to same Partition.

What is the difference between this, and using `CustomPartitioner`? I hope Custom Partitioner also used to send the message to same partition based on Key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default partitioning strategy is

1. If a partition is specified in the record, use it
2. If no partition is specified but a key is present choose a partition based on a hash of the key
3. If no partition or key is present choose a partition in a round-robin fashion

(This is pulled from the `DefaultPartitioner` source code)

The custom partitioner just lets you set your own strategy. So you could for example assign partitions randomly or if you somehow have prior knowledge of how large the partition will be assign it based off that. The default part of `DefaultPartitioner` is more about the round robin strategy. I'd imagine in most/all situations option 1 and 2 would be considered the norm.